# Return Boolean to outer function - Javascript

Tags: javascript

The code is as follows

```
validateItems = (order, action) => {
    let hasError = false;
    orders.map(order => {
      if (this.hasLineItemFormErrors(order, action)) hasError = true;
    });
    return hasError;
  };
hasLineItemFormErrors = (order, action) => {
    let hasError = false;
    this.getLineItemsForms(order.id).map(form => {
      if (form.hasError) hasError = true;
    });
    return hasError;
  };
```

As you can see, i have to repeat the `hasError` variable on each method. Is there a more cleaner way to write this?

Something like

```
hasLineItemFormErrors = (order, action) => {
        return this.getLineItemsForms(order.id).map(form => {
          if (form.hasError) return true;
        }); // When there are no errors, this will return formsArray,  so the hasError variable in parent method becomes true
      };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you can get rid of both the methods and use Array.some ?

```
validateItems = (order, action) => {
    return orders.some(order => this.hasLineItemFormErrors(order, action))
};
hasLineItemFormErrors = (order, action) => {
    return this.getLineItemsForms(order.id).some(form => form.hasError);
};
```

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, you should use Array.some for that:

```
const validateItems = (orders, action) => {
    return orders.some(order => this.getLineItemsForms(order.id).some(form => form.hasError))
}
```

This will return true or false if one of the orders has at least one error.